# Функция возвращает многократно один и тот же результат

Tags: sql, функции, oracle

Есть следующая функция:

```
create or replace FUNCTION PER_FNC 
( ID_Des IN int )
RETURN integer IS 

cursor sr is 
    Select id_d  from deliveries where id_d=ID_Des;

st integer;
se integer;

BEGIN
   open sr;
   fetch sr into st;
   close sr;
Return st;
END PER_FNC;
```

Создавалась сначала более сложная версия, в попытке разобраться в проблеме функцию упростил максимально. Функция должна выводить `Id` доставки

Проблема в том,что функция выводит `Id` доставки столько раз, сколько строк в таблице `Deliveries`.
В курсоре с `distinct`, `order by`, `group by` и без всего, выводит одинаковый результат, из-за чего пришел к выводу, что функция как-то зациклилась.

Не могу понять причину проблемы. Вот данные и как вызываю:

[image: Таблица Deliveries]

```
select Per_fnc(1) from deliveries;
```

[image: Вывод функции]

Comment: приведите пример/запрос как вы вызываете  функцию

Comment: У вас всё работает как задумано. Почему вы считаете результат неверным?

Comment: @0xdb, Видимо он имеет ввиду, что хочет чтобы в данном случае вернулось только одно единственное значение с `id_d` равным 1

Comment: @Александр Это я понял. Но хотел бы услышать ответ ТС, т.к чтобы лучше помочь надо знать не только, как он видит желаемый результат, а **почему** он его таким видит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> из-за чего пришел к выводу, что функция как-то зациклилась

Нет, не зациклилась. Функция в `SELECT` листе будет вызвана для каждой записи результата запроса, независимо от того, что функция делает и каков её результат.

Есть три способа вызвать функцию, первые два в SQL, последний, в PL/SQL контекстах выполнения:

```
create or replace function func (num  number) return number is
begin return num; end;
/
var res number
--#1
select func (1) res from dual;
--#2
call func (1) into :res;
--#3
execute :res := func (1)
```

Все они дадут один и тот же результат:

```
       RES
----------
         1
```